# Concatenate list of lists into new list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have few lists that I want to concatenate into a new list of lists. For example, a list might look like this:

```
[[],  []]
[[3], [1]]
[[],  [5]]
[[2,5], []]
```

and based on this I want the output to look like:

```
[[3, 2, 5], [1,5]]
```

We cannot assume anything about the length of the lists (they will not always have two elements in the beginning, they might have more).

Here is the code I tried:

```
list1[l] += list2[l] #where l is an index
```

Comment: Do you guarantee that the number of objects in each top-level list is the same?)

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? What did not work? Post your code.

Comment: @Grigoriy yes they will always match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know that  each top-level list shape matches all others, then we can do something like this using list comprehensions:

```
lists = [
         [[],  []],
         [[3], [1]],
         [[],  [5]],
         [[2,5], []],
    ]
shape=len(lists[0])
res = [[val  for lst in lists for val in lst[i]] for i in range(shape) ]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 2, 5], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[[],  []],[[3], [1]],[[],  [5]],[[2,5], []]]

lstFinal = []
for i in range(0,len(lst[0])):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,len(lst)):
        temp.extend(lst[j][i])
    lstFinal.append(temp)
print(lstFinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

a = [[],  []]
b = [[3], [1]]
c = [[],  [5]]
d = [[2,5], []]

# transpose
z = zip(a, b, c, d)
# list(z) --> [([], [3], [], [2, 5]), ([], [1], [5], [])]

# flatten
def f(t):
    return reduce(add, t)

m = map(f, z)

# result    
for thing in m:
    print(thing)

>>>
[3, 2, 5]
[1, 5]
>>>
```